# Filter records by string using wildcard in any position

Tags: c#, filter, wildcard

I'd like to filter records with lambda expression. The condition is if it contains a given string, or nearly the same string with one character difference.
Nearly the same means: one of the characters can be any character, but only one.

For example:
The search string: 'ABC' then the condition must be: '[any char]BC' or 'A[any char]C' or 'AB[any char]'

Does anyone know any professional solution?
Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION (thanks for LiamK):

```
         var count = s1.Zip(s2, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 ? 0 : 1).Sum();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `lambda expression`? Lambda expressions are basically just methods. Do you mean LINQ?

Comment: I'd like to use lambda for filtering like: db.Things.Where( [expression[ )

Comment: How could you solve this with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric you are looking for is referred to as the [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance between two strings. You can create an implementation of this algorithm, then utilize it inside of your where clause:

```
public IEnumerable<string> MyFunc(string searchString)
{
    return myThingToSearch.Where(x => LevenshteinDistance(x, searchString) <= 1);
}

public static int LevenshteinDistance(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1 == s2)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (s1.Length == 0)
    {
        return s2.Length;
    }

    if (s2.Length == 0)
    {
        return s1.Length;
    }

    int[] v0 = new int[s2.Length + 1];
    int[] v1 = new int[s2.Length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < v0.Length; i++)
    {
        v0[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
    {
        v1[0] = i + 1;

        for (int j = 0; j < s2.Length; j++)
        {
            var cost = (s1[i] == s2[j]) ? 0 : 1;
            v1[j + 1] = Math.Min(v1[j] + 1, Math.Min(v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < v0.Length; j++)
        {
            v0[j] = v1[j];
        }
    }
    return v1[s2.Length];
}
```

Side note: The Levenshtein distance metric will also match strings like 'BC' or 'ABCD' to the search string 'ABC' since those strings are technically only 'off-by-one' from the search string. I'm not sure if this is acceptable within your spec or not. If not, then let us know. That problem is a subset of approximate string matching and you would use the [Hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) distance instead

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer! I solved it with Hamming distance.

Comment: Glad I could help! Sleek implementation of the Hamming distance algorithm.